# force directed graph different cluster for different groups

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

From past few days I have been googling around in `D3.JS` library. Its a Great Visualization library indeed.

I have used Force Directed Graph for the representation of data of social networks. Until now its fine but all the different groups of different color are coming together.

What I want to do is to define different cluster for each node. So that same color nodes come together in one cluster.

How can I do so ?

My current Force directed graph looks like [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/gCnDBzGsu2LzOwuTWmOn?p=preview)

Comment: Have you seen [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7882658)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally Solved my problem with the following lines of code

```
    function tick(e) {
  // Push different nodes in different directions for clustering.
  var k = 6 * e.alpha;
  graph.nodes.forEach(function(o, i) {
    o.y += i & 1 ? k : -k;
    o.x += i & 2 ? k : -k;
  });
  node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });

}
```